# При взломе wi-fi через airodump-ng не вижу других клиентов кроме себя

Tags: wifi, взлом

Читал про то, как взламывать wi-fi и кое чего не понимаю.

Первое действие написано: `sudo ifconfig`

Второе действие: `sudo airmon-ng start (тут свой адаптер)`

Третье действие: `повторить первое`

Четвертое действие: `sudo airodump-ng mon0`

После этого, по идее, я должен увидеть wifi сети и клиентов, которые к ним подключены. Но я вижу только себя. Почему так происходит? У всех гайдов видно несколько клиентов. Это виноват адаптер в компьютере или что то другое?

Comment: Короче, я спросил на форуме, мне там помогли. Оказывается, я ничего не видел, потому что был слабый адаптер. Купил на алиэкспрес адаптер за 100 рублей и с ним появились устройства, с которых я могу перехватывать рукопожатия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильный ответ: если такое происходит, то возможно виноват слабый wi-fi адаптер, что было у меня. С другим адаптером точки для перехвата появились.

Answer (score 1):

На хороших роутерах админы обычно ставят изоляцию клиентов. Каждый клиент получает только предназначенный ему трафик. Это как второй вариант отсутствия трафика.